# How save multiples values into a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv

I have a code that returns different values computed from short protein sequences, however when I tried to save these inside a csv file, only the last value is saved. How can I save them all?

My code:

```
with open('seq.txt', 'r') as f:
    for sequence in f:
        import random

        molDes_01 = {'A': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'L': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'R': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'K': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'N': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'M': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'D': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'F': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'C': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'P': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'Q': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'S': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'E': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'T': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'G': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'W': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'H': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'Y':random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0),
                     'I': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0), 'V': random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)}

        aaindex_values = []
        aaindex_listT = [molDes_01]
        for i in aaindex_listT:
            a_a = sequence.count("A") * i["A"]
            c_c = sequence.count("C") * i["C"]
            d_d = sequence.count("D") * i["D"]
            e_e = sequence.count("E") * i["E"]
            f_f = sequence.count("F") * i["F"]
            g_g = sequence.count("G") * i["G"]
            h_h = sequence.count("H") * i["H"]
            i_i = sequence.count("I") * i["I"]
            k_k = sequence.count("K") * i["K"]
            l_l = sequence.count("L") * i["L"]
            m_m = sequence.count("M") * i["M"]
            n_n = sequence.count("N") * i["N"]
            p_p = sequence.count("P") * i["P"]
            q_q = sequence.count("Q") * i["Q"]
            r_r = sequence.count("R") * i["R"]
            s_s = sequence.count("S") * i["S"]
            t_t = sequence.count("T") * i["T"]
            v_v = sequence.count("V") * i["V"]
            w_w = sequence.count("W") * i["W"]
            y_y = sequence.count("Y") * i["Y"]

            values = (a_a + c_c + d_d + e_e + f_f + g_g + h_h + i_i + k_k + l_l + m_m + n_n + p_p + q_q + r_r + s_s + t_t + v_v + w_w + y_y)/len(sequence)
            aaindex_values.append(values)

            for j in aaindex_values:
                import csv

                with open('process.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
                    writer = csv.writer(file)
                    writer.writerow([j])
```

The contents of the 'seq.txt' file are several short sequences, see below:

```
CVCVKTTSLVRPRHI
GLNGPDIYKGUYQFK
RRKKLAALPLVLAAP
RWRWRWRW
RWRWRWRWRW
SDDPKESEGDLHCVC
ALNTLVKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRL
```

Comment: open the file in append mode as in the doc.

Comment: `aaindex_values` will only ever have but one element in it, so the `for i in aaindex_listT:` only iterates once. The `for j in aaindex_values:` loop at the end also only iterates once, but even it it did multiple times, each time it would overwrite the previous file.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, please do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2):

By putting the `with open()` block inside the for loop, you're closing and then re-opening the file every time you write a row. When you open a file in write mode (`'w'`), that erases anything that was already in the file. This means that your code is writing every row, but then deleting what it just wrote as soon as it goes onto the next row.

One way to fix this is to use `'a'` instead of `'w'`, to open the file in append mode instead of write mode:

```
import csv  # No need to import this multiple times inside the loop   

for j in aaindex_values:
    with open('process.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([j])
```

But a much cleaner way is to move all of the file logic outside the loop, so you don't need to close and reopen the file multiple times, create multiple csv writers, etc:

```
import csv  

with open('process.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for j in aaindex_values:
        writer.writerow([j])
```